# Loop over an Object and group every 4 items in an array within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

Let's say I have the following object:

```
{
  A1: {name: "x", age: y},
  B1: {name: "x", age: y},
  C1: {name: "x", age: y},
  D1: {name: "x", age: y},
  A2: {name: "x", age: y},
  B2: {name: "x", age: y},
  C2: {name: "x", age: y},
  D2: {name: "x", age: y},
  A3: {name: "x", age: y},
  B3: {name: "x", age: y},
  C3: {name: "x", age: y},
  D3: {name: "x", age: y},
}
```

But I need it to be like this:

```
[
  {
    A1: {name: "x", age: y},
    B1: {name: "x", age: y},
    C1: {name: "x", age: y},
    D1: {name: "x", age: y},
  },
  {
    A2: {name: "x", age: y},
    B2: {name: "x", age: y},
    C2: {name: "x", age: y},
    D2: {name: "x", age: y},
  },
  {
    A3: {name: "x", age: y},
    B3: {name: "x", age: y},
    C3: {name: "x", age: y},
    D3: {name: "x", age: y},
  }
]
```

I've tried with for loops and maps but just got stucked, not achieving the desired result

Comment: your desired output is invalid.

Comment: @JonasWilms my bad, just fixed it

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
  const hash = {};

  for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(input)) {
    const [letter, num] = key;
    if(!hash[num]) hash[num] = {};
    hash[num][key] = value;
  }

  const result = Object.values(hash);
```